# Codeigniter select query return all rows while reading varchar where as null

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I was testing since yesterday this query in codeigniter and always I get an empty result or all the rows of my table.

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('node');
$this->db->where('mac_node',$mac_node);

$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result();
```

I tried to read the last query and this is the result:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `node` WHERE `mac_node` =0
```

I don't know where is the problem. I set the where value manually as a `varchar` and I get the correct result

Comment: may be you don't have value in $mac_node.

Comment: it looks like it can't read my $mac_node value but when I change my code $this->db->where('mac_node',"fde95fds5d"); I get the result.

Comment: yeah. that's the issue. try to get value in $mac_node

Comment: my code always read the input as an empty value I don't know why. I don't have a problem with post function I only have with get function

Comment: In your controller check the variable $mac_node value first and then call the function in your model. if(!empty($mac_node)){ // Function call }

Comment: Now I can read the input value and I don't know how it has been fixed. Another thing we should write the varchar without "".

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to get `Null` Records

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('node');

>  $this->db->where('mac_node IS NULL');  

$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result();
```